# Looping and inserting values in keys of hash in angular2

Tags: angular

I am new in angular2 and I want to loop keys and change user_id to user name.This is the code of user.component.ts. In response I am getting like this: [{"1":"Begginer ,professional ,"},{"2":"Begginer"},{"4":"Professional, freshers"}] and I want to display it like:

A Begginer,professional

B Begineer

C Professional,fresher

A B C is user name.

```
this.userCategories = response;
console.log(JSON.stringify(this.userCategories)); //[{"1":"Begginer ,professional ,"},{"2":"Begginer"},{"4":"Professional, freshers"}]
this.userCategories =  this.userCategories.map( i => {
  let user = [];
  let usr = [];
  const User_id = Object.keys(i)[0]; // here I am getting user_id
  for(let j of User_id){
    this.userService.userName(j).subscribe(
     name => {
       usr.push(name); // pushing name of users in an array.
       return usr;
     },
     err => {
       console.log('err:', err);
     }
    );
  }
  user[0] = usr;
  console.log(user[0]); // here I am getting username in an array.
  user[1] = i[User_id];
  return user;
})
```

Then in view when I am using like this:

```
<a >{{userCategories[0] | json}}</b>
<a >{{userCategories[1]}}</a>
```

I am getting:

```
  [ "\"A \"" ] Begineers,professional
  [ "\"B \"" ] Begineers
  [ "\"C \"" ] Professional,fresher
```

Could anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something Like : -

```
let response = [{ "1": "Begineer ,professional ," }, { "2": "Begineer" }, { "4": "Professional, freshers" }];  //JSON Array  [{"1":"Begineer ,professional ,"},{"2":"Begineer"},{"4":"Professional, freshers"}]
/**
 * Please make sure map always return array
 * map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element.
 * 
 * And your parsing as Object {"A" : "Begineer,professional"}
 * 
 * to make it as Object use it as
 */
response.map((value, key) => {
    //Get UserName By UserID Function 
    let userId = Object.keys(value)[0];
    this._service.username(userId).subscribe(name => {
        this.userCategories.push({key : name , username : value[userId]}) ;
    })
})
```

Since *ngFor works with array I have converted it as array ..

Please Update your view as :-

```
<div *ngFor="let user of userCategories">
        <p>
                <a>{{user.key}}</a>
                <a>{{user.username}}</a>
        </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have edited my question like you have posted but I am not getting the output.

Comment: *ngFor only work for array not object ,, please see updated answer

Comment: Thanks @Double H, Now I am getting this in browser console.
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined

Comment: try `<a>{{user?.key}}</a><a>{{user?.username}}</a>`.. and tell me

Comment: Thanks @Double H , I got the output.